# Gauss-Newton products in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use the Gauss-Newton approximation to the Hessian as a metric for an optimization problem, such as the method used to fit the value function in GAE https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438. However, does anyone know how to efficiently compute these products? The issue is that I can not compute Jacobian off the shelf in Tensorflow, which makes it hard to do the per example one-rank computations. One solution is given in this technical report https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.01799.pdf, however, this puts some constraints on the network architectures that can be used. Does it exist a more general solution?

Answer (score 0):

As of april 2017 there is no general-purpose efficient way to compute per-example gradients in TensorFlow, calling `tf.gradients` on all examples is probably the best for now.